# ASPNETCORE_URLS ARG not used when running docker-compose up

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have an ASP.NET Core API with a Postgres Db. I am trying to Dockerize the whole application.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# set base image as the dotnet 2.2 SDK.
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env

# set the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD
# instructions that follows the WORKDIR instruction.
WORKDIR /app

# our current working directory within the container is /app
# we now copy all the files (from local machine) to /app (in the container).
COPY . ./

# again, on the container (we are in /app folder)
# we now publish the project into a folder called 'out'.
RUN dotnet publish Bejebeje.Api/Bejebeje.Api.csproj -c Release -o out

# set base image as the dotnet 2.2 runtime.
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime

# local variable
ARG customport

# temporary test to make sure the variable is coming through.
RUN echo "ASPNETCORE_URLS -> $customport"

# telling the application what port to run on.
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=$customport

# set the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD
# instructions that follows the WORKDIR instruction.
WORKDIR /app

# copy the contents of /app/out in the `build-env` and paste it in the
# `/app` directory of the new runtime container.
COPY --from=build-env /app/Bejebeje.Api/out .

# set the entry point into the application.
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Bejebeje.Api.dll", "-seed"]
```

And here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  bejebeje-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Bejebeje.Api/Dockerfile
      args:
        - customport=http://*5005
      labels:
        com.bejebeje.description: "Bejebeje's API"
    image: bejebeje-api:latest
    ports:
      - "5005:5005"
    env_file:
      - ./variables.env
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8002:5432"
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./variables.env

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

I first run `docker-compose build` and I can see

```
Step 7/12 : RUN echo "ASPNETCORE_URLS -> $customport"
 ---> Running in cd127d488021
ASPNETCORE_URLS -> http://*5005
```

So my custom argument is coming through, but when I run `docker-compose up`, the application still runs on port `80` and not `5005`.

My `variables.env` has the following:

```
FrontendCorsOrigin=http://localhost:1234
ApiName=bejebeje-api
Authority=http://localhost:5000
Database__DefaultConnectionString=Server=database;Port=5432;Database=DbName;User Id=postgres;Password=awesomePass;
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=awesomePass
POSTGRES_DB=DbName
```

[image: cmd]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the contents of your variables.env file?

Comment: Can you change the ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile and just run "env" in there? This way you can see all the environment variables at runtime. All looks good but somehow you might overwrite that variable by mistake. This is a way to check this.

Comment: I've added the content of `variables.env` to the question.

Comment: You should add the env var to this file if you want to use it in runtime.

Comment: You might be missing a colon before the port name: ` - customport=http://*:5005`

Comment: @YaronIdan I've gone ahead and added `APP_PORT=http://*:5005` (fixed missing colon suggested by @ESG) to my `variables.env`. When I run `docker-compose up`, I now get: https://www.screencast.com/t/uMn4jvMAm. It still doesn't run on `5005`, I've no idea where it grabbed `5000` from!

Comment: Might be the `Authority` env var? Also, you say you've added `APP_PORT` but in your Dockerfile the env var's name was `ASPNETCORE_URLS`, why not use that name?

Comment: I thought maybe that name was used in the Microsoft docker image, does the name matter though? Also, when doing `docker-compose build`, should the variable be read from the `variables.env` and substituted? Right now it isn't: https://www.screencast.com/t/lDpmtvc40

Comment: Yes, the name matters. Check out this link - https://riptutorial.com/asp-net-core/example/7433/kestrel--configuring-listening-address. The `variables.env` file is only read when the running container is launched, build environments get their environment variables from the dockerfile and your `docker-compose.yaml` build section.

Answer (score -2):

This is not 100% answer to your question, but you should try to use another method to define URLs for an ASP.NET Core app.

For example use **UseUrls()** for **.NET5** and lower.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5005");
            });
```

Or **ListenAnyIP()** for **.NET6**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//...

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ListenAnyIP(5005);
});

//...

var app = builder.Build();
```

Check the link for more (may not every solution would work inside docker container): https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/